# Notepad++ copy email characters on every line and add to the end of every line

Tags: notepad++, prefix

I have a list like this

```
hulkingmuseum46@superrito.com:KTUKEBZHV
boorishsanity62@superrito.com:KLRPDXXQG
functionalsumma@superrito.com:FBXSTFVES
furtivetelegram@superrito.com:HJLYZWKFK
```

I want to copy the characters email of each line and paste it on the end of each lines with ::0::: so it will become like this

```
hulkingmuseum46@superrito.com:KTUKEBZHV::0:::hulkingmuseum46@superrito.com
boorishsanity62@superrito.com:KLRPDXXQG::0:::boorishsanity62@superrito.com
functionalsumma@superrito.com:FBXSTFVES::0:::functionalsumma@superrito.com
furtivetelegram@superrito.com:HJLYZWKFK::0:::furtivetelegram@superrito.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really suited to Stack Overflow... But... Find and replace

Find: `(.*):(.*)`

Replace: `\1:\2::0:::\1`

Comment: And make sure 'Regular expression' is selected under 'Search Mode'

Answer (score -2):

I would record a macro that does

End
Ctrl-Left
Ctrl-Left
Shift-Home
Ctrl-C
End
::0:::
Ctrl-V
Home
Down

Then you just need to play the macro

Comment: Seems a little over complicated for a simple search and replace?

Comment: Depends if you know regex or not. Looks long but it's actually pretty quick.